# prove a matrix UDU* is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove the following:

Prove that if $V=UDU^{\dagger}$ with D having only modulus one values, then $V$ must be unitary.

Could someone please explain to me what is exactly meant by "modulus one values"? and how do I prove it?

I was thinking to prove it by proving that $UDU^{\dagger}$  $(UDU^{\dagger})^{\dagger}$  = $(UDU^{\dagger})^{\dagger} UDU^{\dagger} = I$      but I'm not sure what D is...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D= diag(d_1,...,d_n)$ with $|d_j|=1$ for $j=1,...,n,$ then

$$ d_j \bar d_j=|d_j|^2=1$$

for $j=1,...,n,$ hence

$$D^*D=DD^*=I.$$

Now show that $V$ is unitary.

Comment: thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $D$ is a diagonal matrix such that all entries from the main diagonal have absolute value equal to $1$.

Comment: thanks for your answer :)